# Vuetify breadcrumbs scoped slot

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to incorporate breadcrumbs into my vuetify app however this is my code:

```
<v-breadcrumbs divider=">">
    <v-breadcrumbs-item
        v-for="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs"
        exact
        :to="breadcrumb.to">
        {{ breadcrumb.text }}
    </v-breadcrumbs-item>
</v-breadcrumbs>
```

And then I get this warning in the console. Im not really sure what it means..

`default slot' is deprecated, use ':items and scoped slot "item"' instead`

If i try the default template from vuetify docs: `<v-breadcrumbs :items="items">` it only allows for a `href` not a `:to` which is what I need.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that Veutify now provides an `item` scoped slot that can be used to customize breadcrumbs. Looking at their example [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/breadcrumbs) I think what you need to do is the following ..

```
<v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbs" divider=">">
    <v-breadcrumbs-item
        slot="item"
        slot-scope="{ item }"
        exact
        :to="item.to">
        {{ item.text }}
    </v-breadcrumbs-item>
</v-breadcrumbs>
```

Comment: When I use that code I just get a whole load of errors `Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Just remove the colon from `slot-scope`.

Answer (score 4):

alternative is use a method with a click event

```
<template>
  <v-breadcrumbs divider=">">
    <v-breadcrumbs-item
        v-for="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs"
        exact
        @click="goTo(breadcrumb.to)">
        {{ breadcrumb.text }}
    </v-breadcrumbs-item>
  </v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      goTo (payload) {
        this.$router.push(payload)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which is much simpler compare to the above solutions:

```js
<template>
  <v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbs">
    <template v-slot:divider>
      <v-icon>mdi-menu-right</v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      breadcrumbs: [
        {
          nuxt: true,
          activeClass: "",
          text: "Page A",
          to: { name: "page-a" },
        },
        {
          disabled: true,
          text: "Page B",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from the official [website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/breadcrumbs/#icon-dividers),

```html
<template>
  <v-breadcrumbs :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <v-breadcrumbs-item
        :href="item.href"
        :disabled="item.disabled"
      >
        {{ item.text.toUpperCase() }}
      </v-breadcrumbs-item>
    </template>
  </v-breadcrumbs>
</template>
```